# Can I use a Template DOM repeater based on the number of child elements of <contents>

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I was contemplating some code which would wrap each child of of the web component.  Something like:

```
<dom-module id=test">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{contents.children}}">
      <div>
        {{item}}
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

so what would happen is if i did something like:

```
<test>
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</test>
```

it would kick out:

```
<test>
  <div><span>foo</span></div>
  <div><span>bar</span></div>
</test>
```

I was looking over ways i could do this, but i am having issues trying to create the dom-repeat correctly since `contents.children` isnt a real property.

**Edit** i was looking at what attributes are allowed for content tags, which is *select* plus all globals.

So in theory, i could assign an ID and then get the children of it?

```
<content id="myContent"></content>
```

and then in the dart say:

```
ContentElement get _content => $['myContent'];
@property HtmlElement children = [];

a.created(): super.created(){
  set("children", _content.children);
}
```

and then mark the template accordingly?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{children}}">
  ...
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would like to wrap certain elements and add some new functionality to them.

The simplest (and most Polymer-ish) way to do that, is to introduce *another* custom element, which is (only) responsible for the wrapping.

Your `test` element (which, by the way, has an incorrect name - the name **must** contain a dash) would then look like this:

```
<dom-module id=test-element">
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

(I fixed the naming according to convention. Renamed from `test` to `test-element`.)

And the newly created wrapper element (named `wrapper-element`) should look something like this:

```
<dom-module id=wrapper-element">
  <template>
    <div><content></content></div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Everything put together, the usage would be something like this:

```
<test-element>
  <wrapper-element><span>foo</span></wrapper-element>
  <wrapper-element><span>bar</span></wrapper-element>
</test-element>
```

With this, you get a clean solution, where you don't even need any JS code for the wrapping logic.